# How can I get SVN to recognize Mac Bundles as ASCII instead of Binary Streams?

Tags: mac, git, svn, iwork-keynote

I have a keynote file in which I am regularly editing the text, moving slides around, etc. There are a max of a few kilobytes of data changed in the internal .key XML file. However, SVN recognizes this as a bundle and checks in the entire .3gb "file" with each change (I have a lot of high-res videos.) This is clearly not ideal. Is there any way to get SVN to recognize bundles as directories?

A similar answer for Git would be appreciated as well.

Comment: If it's zipped together in some way like ODF or OOXML files, you're probably SOL. That said, I've not used Keynote, so I couldn't say.

Comment: It's quite literally a folder, but with a bit set to make the OS "pretend" it's a file ([explanation](http://guides.macrumors.com/Bundle)). So when git sees it, it thinks it's a file, and ignores the contents of the directory. I'm not sure when the compression takes place.

Comment: I'm guessing it's similar to how it handles .app "files". Can you do an `ls` on the bundle and get the directory contents?

Comment: Looks like I am mistaken- the keynote is a Zip file, not a bundle. With proper search terms, I found a blog with a start: http://tante.cc/2010/06/23/managing-zip-based-file-formats-in-git/ - this will allow "git diff" to unzip the files and look at that diff. I'll look into combining this with commits.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer, so this won't be listed as "unanswered".

Comment: I refined the information from the comments and a bit of reasearch on keynote files to an answer.

Comment: You can use 'keynote-to-text' to diff keynote files. It integrates with GitHub smoothly: https://github.com/robertoaloi/keynote-to-text

Answer (score 1):

Up to Keynote' 06 the `.keynote` file was actually a folder <sup>[1](http://www.file-extensions.org/keynote-file-extension)</sup> like you mentioned.
However, later the `.key` format is used and this is a zip file. <sup>[2](http://www.file-extensions.org/key-file-extension-iwork-keynote-09-presentation-file)</sup>

ZIP files are not a good format to be diffed, but you can add unzip as a [diff handler](http://tante.cc/2010/06/23/managing-zip-based-file-formats-in-git/) in git.

You can also save the presentation in the old `.keynote` format.
If svn still thinks the file is binary, you can use `svn add --no-auto-props` or `svn propdel svn:mime-type`.
Files with no mime-type are treated as text files by subversion. <sup>[3](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files)</sup>